# How know if a command given to exec exists?

Tags: c, fork, exec, parent-child

I've searched quite a lot, but I still don't have an answer for this. I've got a program that working like a shell and asking the user the desired command, then I use execlp to open this new process. I wanted to know if there's an easy way to find out if the command was executed, or if the received command doesn't exist.

I use the following code:

```
execlp(argv[0], argv[0], (char *)NULL);
```

Comment: A Google search of "What is the return value of execlp" might be useful. It's also useful to think about your question before posting; if you never check the results of doing something, how would you expect to know whether it worked or not?

Comment: Note that `execl()` is probably not the function you’ll be using long term. You’ll need to use `execvp()` in general because you won’t know how many arguments are needed and `execlp()` requires you to put an upper bound on the number of arguments at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

If the specified couldn't be found, then execlp will return - 1 and set errno to ENOENT.
So you can check,

```
if (errno == ENOENT)
  printf("Command not found");
```

In your parent process.

Comment: It might set EPERM (no permission), or various other errors too.  But you’re right. If it returns, it failed. You don’t even need to check the value; if it returns, it failed.